# ‎If ‎‎$‎X$ is an infinite-dimensional Banach space and ‎‎$‎‎u‎\in ‎B(X)‎$ ,then $\bigcap_{v\in K(X)}\sigma(u+v) =\cdots$

Tags: operator-theory, banach-algebras

‎If ‎‎$‎X$ is an infinite-dimensional Banach space and ‎‎$‎‎u‎\in ‎B(X)‎$,why the following equality is true?

$$\bigcap_{v\in K(X)}\sigma(u+v) =\sigma(u) \setminus \{\lambda \in\mathbb{C}\mid u - \lambda \text{ is Fredholm of index zero} \}$$
‎‎‎
The index of $‎‎u‎\in A$ is defined to be

$$\operatorname{ind}(u)=\operatorname{nul}(u)-\operatorname{def}(u)$$
where co-dimension of $u(X)$ in $Y$ be denoted by $\operatorname{def}(u)$ and $\dim(\ker(u))$ denoted by $\operatorname{nul}(u)$

$u\in B(X,Y)$ is Fredholm operator, if $\ker(u)$ is finite-dimensional and $u(X)$ is finite-co-dimensional in $Y$

$$K(X,X):=K(X)=\{u : X \longrightarrow X\mid u\text{ is compact operator}\} ‎$$

Comment: The set of all compact operator from X to X is denoted by K(X)

Comment: @AliQurbani : I cleaned up your TeX usage and you undid it.  Your style of using TeX results in something that looks as if it was done by a kindergartner with a crayon.  It wouldn't hurt you to learn to use TeX properly.

Comment: Hello @Ali Qurbani  can you please add a full answer for the second direction, the answer below, it does not mention all the details..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reference: Schecter, "Principles of Functional Analysis", pg. 180. The object on the left hand side is known as the Essential Spectrum $(\sigma_e(u))$.

One direction is not so hard; if $\lambda \notin \sigma_e(u)$ then for some $K$ compact we have that $u + K - \lambda$ is invertible. This implies that $\lambda \in \Phi(u+K)$ and $i(u+K - \lambda) = 0$. Recall now that compact perturbations of Fredholm operators are fredholm, and that such perturbations preserve the index $i$. So perturb $u+K-\lambda$ by $-K$, and we see that $u-\lambda$ is fredholm with index zero.

The other direction is trickier; check the reference for the details. The idea is to construct an operator $F$ of finite rank such that $N(u-\lambda) \cap N(F) = \{0\}$ and $R(u - \lambda) \cap R(F) = \{0\}$. Equipped with this, $u-\lambda+F$ is both Fredholm of index zero and injective; thus $\lambda$ belongs to the resolvent set of $u+F$. As operators of finite rank are compact, we're done.

Answer (score 0):

I confess this was an exam question for me yesterday and (surprisingly) I was only able to prove the inclusion Blumenthal mentions to be harder, namely:

> $$\cap_{S\in \mathcal{K}(X)}\sigma(T+S)\subseteq\sigma(T)\setminus\{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}\:| \: \text{$T-\lambda$ is fredholm and $ind(T-\lambda)=0$} \}$$

$\lambda \in \cap_{S\in \mathcal{K}(X)}\sigma(T+S)$. If $T-\lambda$ were invertible:

$$T+S-\lambda=(T-\lambda)(I+(T-\lambda)^{-1}S)$$

But this is the composition of invertible operators for $S$ compact with small norm because of Von Neumann. Hence, we conclude that:

$$\cap_{S\in \mathcal{K}(X)}\sigma(T+S)\subseteq \sigma(T)$$

Suppose by way of contradiction that:

$$\left(\cap_{S\in \mathcal{K}(X)}\sigma(T+S)\right)\cap\{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}\:| \: \text{$T-\lambda$ is fredholm and $ind(T-\lambda)=0$} \}\not=\emptyset$$

In this case, we have that:

$$Ker(T-\lambda)\:  \text{has basis given by} \:\{ x_1,...,x_n\}$$

$$ Im(T-\lambda)\:  \text{has complemented space with basis given by} \:\{ y_1,...,y_n\}$$

Take $U$ which takes $U(x_i)=y_i$ for $i=1,...,n$ and extend it continuously by Hahn Banach. Perhaps this needs a little more justification. We take $U_i(x_i)=\delta_{ij}$ defined in the Kernel and make $U_i\in X^*$ by Hahn Banach. Of course we actually mean $U(x)=\sum U_i(x)y_i$ which is continuous by construction, with norm bounded by $\sum_{i=1}^n \lVert U_i\rVert\lVert y_i\rVert$ . We notice that because  $Im(T-\lambda)$ is complemented, there is a projection $\pi_Y$ whose image is precisely the complement. $\pi_Y\circ U$ is a finite rank operator, hence compact. It is not hard to see that:

$$T-\lambda +\pi_Y \circ U$$

is in fact invertible. Indeed, now are able to attain any point and we have annihilated the kernel.

---

> $$\sigma(T)\setminus\{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}\:| \: \text{$T-\lambda$ is fredholm and $ind(T-\lambda)=0$} \}\subseteq\cap_{S\in \mathcal{K}(X)}\sigma(T+S)$$

This inclusion I was not able to solve, but apparently it is clearer if we remember pertubation by compact operator preserves index. Let us copy Blumenthal's argument. Take $\lambda $ in the righthandside and suppose by way of contradiction that there exists some compact $S$ such that $T+S-\lambda$ is invertible.

$$T-\lambda=T-\lambda+S-S=(T-\lambda+S)(I-(T-\lambda+S)^{-1}S)$$

Because composition of Fredholm operators is Fredholm, then $T-\lambda$ is Fredholm and $T-\lambda$ has the same index as $T+S-\lambda$ because we added a compact operator from one to the other. But this is absurd as we should have $T-\lambda$ not to be Fredholm or $ind(T-\lambda)\not=0$