# Fredholm and Compact Operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces and $T\in B(X,Y)$ be Fredholm. Then there is  $S\in B(Y,X)$ such that $ST=I+K_{1}$ and $TS=I+K_{2}$ where $K_{1},K_{2}$ are compact operators.
**Proof**: Since $T$ is Fredholm then $KerT$ and $Coker(ImT)$ are finite diminsional and hence complimented, so assume $X=KerT\oplus V$ and $Y=ImT\oplus W$. Now define $T_{v}$ to be the restriction of the map $T$  to $V$ that is $$T_{v}:V\longrightarrow ImT$$ by definition we have $T$ is a bijection and $V$ and $ImT$ are Banach spaces then by the open mapping theorem $S_{1}=T_{v}^{-1}$ is bounded, Now consider $S:Y\longrightarrow X$ defined by $$S(y)=S_{1}P(y)$$ where P is the projection from $Y\longrightarrow ImT$ QED.

**Question**: a) If $T$ is Fredholm and $Ind(T)=n(T)-d(T)=0$, how can I change the proof to say that $S$ can be chosen to be invertible not only bounded. where $n(T)$ is the dimention of the kernel and $d(T)$ is the dimension of the cokerT.
b) Let $X$ be a Banach space and $T\in B(X)$ show that$$\bigcap_{K\in K(X)}\sigma(T+K)=\sigma(T)-\{\lambda:\lambda I-T\text{ is Fredholm of Index zero}\}.$$
**Note**: I'm really stuck on part a, as for part b) I'm trying to use the fact that $T$ is Fredholm if and only if $T+K(X)$ is invertible in $B(X)/K(X)$ I know that I'm very close but not there yet.

Comment: Part b) is discussed here: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/282195 Can you clarify your question in a)? I'm not sure I understand what you are asking.

Comment: [Also asked on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/120610/).

Comment: A little nitpick, but the fact that the image of $T$ is complemented (as far as I can remember) stems from the fact that it is a *closed* subspace of finite codimension, the important point being the closedness, which is a general property of Fredholm operators. Otherwise, this looks good to me (but I'm not an analyst).

Comment: @OlivierBégassat you are correct

Comment: @Martin the proof i gave is for any Fredholm operator $T$ we can find a bounden operator $S$ such that.... Now if $T$ is Fredholm with index zero then $S$ can be chosen to be invertible not only bounded and I need to show that

Comment: Oh, I missed the assumption index=0 in the question. What does that tell you about $\dim \ker T$ and $\dim W$ and hence about $\ker T$ and $W$? @Olivier: It's actually the proof that $T(X)$ is closed that shows at the same time that it is also complemented: assume wlog $T$ is injective, pick an algebraic complement $Z$ of $T(X)$, show that $X \oplus Z \to Y$ given by $(x,z) \mapsto Tx + z$ is a continuous bijection, so $T(X)$ is closed and complemented by the open mapping theorem.

Comment: @Martin that gives us that dimKertT=dim(Y/ImT)=dim(W)

Comment: Yes, so $\ker T$ and $W$ are isomorphic since they are finite-dimensional. Can you use this to extend $T_{v}^{-1}$ to a continuous linear bijection?

Comment: @Martin I'll have to try, but its a good start thank you.